# TypeError: foundUser.lastLogin.update is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update a field of last login in my mongoose user schema every time a user logs in.

in the user schema, I have this so that upon the user creation, the last login is the date created:

```
lastLogin: {
   type: Date,
   default: Date.now
}
```

In my routes, I have this where I'm attempting to update the `lastLogin` to the time at which the user logged in but it's either coming back that update isn't a function or just not working at all:

```
User.findById(req.user._id, function(err, foundUser) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log("Found user last login is ");
      console.log(foundUser.lastLogin)

      foundUser.lastLogin.update({$set: {'lastLogin': Date.now()}});

      console.log("new last login is")
      console.log(foundUser.lastLogin)
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is how you do it

```
foundUser.update({$set: {'lastLogin': Date.now()}}, function(err,user){
  console.log("new last login is")
  console.log(user.lastLogin)

});
```

What you;re doing is `update` on `lastLogin`, which doesn't have any `update` method on it as it's a property not a document.

Or you can do that all with just `findByIdAndUpdate` with `mongoose` version 4+ like

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id, { $set: { lastLogin: Date.now() }}, {new: true}, function(err,user){
  console.log("new last login is")
  console.log(user.lastLogin)

})
```

`new: bool` - true to return the modified document rather than the original. defaults to false

Comment: that got rid of the error. But the last login is coming back as the created date.

Comment: that is because `.update` is `async` and you are logging to value before the updat resolves. Change your function to updated code

Comment: that returns undefined :/

Comment: what is `mongoose` version you are using ?

Comment: in my package.json it's just an "*" for the version - so the most recent one I believe

Comment: use `{new : true}` as options to update to return the updated doc.